# API to fetch the type of StateNode in Enterprise Architect

Tags: java, enterprise-architect

I have an activity diagram with initial and Final Nodes in it. Both are of type StateNode and the meta type is Pseudostate. How to identify whether a particular node is an initial or final node from the Database or API point of view?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EA.Element.Subtype

From the [documentation](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/automation/element2.html)

> Long
>
> Notes: Read/Write
>
> A numeric subtype that qualifies the Type of the main element
>
> - For Event: 0 = Receiver, 1 = Sender
> - For Class: 1 = Parameterised, 2 =
>   Instantiated, 3 = Both, 0 = Neither, 17 = Association Class
>
> If 17, because an Association Class has been created through the user
> interface, MiscData(3) contains the ID of the related Association; as
> MiscData is read-only, you cannot create an Association Class through
> the Automation Interface.
>
> - For Note: 1 = Note linked to connector, 2 = Constraint linked to
>   connector
> - **For StateNode: 100 = ActivityIntitial, 101 = ActivityFinal**
> - For Activity: 0 = Activity, 8 = composite Activity (also set to 8 for
>   other composite elements such as Use Cases) For Synchronization: 0 =
>   Horizontal, 1 = Vertical
>
> Note that there are many more Types than
> indicated in these examples.